# Equivalent date function in oracle for pd.merge_asof

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any equivalent date function in oracle for python pd.merge_asof? Please see the following example:

Table A1

```
ID      Date
1       12/02/2020
2       11/23/2019
3       09/09/2021
3       10/12/2021
```

Table A2

```
ID      Date
3       09/12/2021
```

For ID = 3, the date is 09/12/2021 in A2 table. When I try to match this ID and date with A1, only ID is matching. So I try to add a logic to get the following output (since it is the closest date).

Output

```
ID       Date        ID2      Date2
3     09/09/2021      3     09/12/2021
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You will get more help if you don't reference other languages (like python), and instead simply state the question in plain English. Given the dates in tables A1 and A2, are you looking - for each date in A2 - to find the closest date in table A1, even if there is no perfect match? If so, a few questions: (1) are you looking both "before" and "after", or only in one direction (e.g. closest date but only BEFORE the date from table A2)? (2) do you need to set a limit, such as "closest, but not off by more than 30 days"?

Comment: (3) What if there are ties for "closest" (two, three, or more ID's all with dates at equal distance from the target date from A2, all equal to the minimum distance)? Return ALL those? Return only one of them, and if so which one? (4) Just for confirmation - you are doing this in addition to matching by ID, which is required - right?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the closest date in A1 where there is no match. Closest date my be before or after, there is no direction. No, there is no limit. The closest date may be for different year.

Comment: If there is a tie between 2 closest date then it chose only one date for that particular ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (join + aggregate):

```
with
  t1 (id, datum) as (
    select 1, date '2020-12-02' from dual union all
    select 2, date '2019-11-23' from dual union all
    select 3, date '2021-09-09' from dual union all
    select 3, date '2021-10-12' from dual
  )
, t2 (id, datum) as (
    select 3, date '2021-09-12' from dual
  )
select t2.id, 
       min(t1.datum) keep (dense_rank first
                 order by abs(t1.datum - t2.datum)) as date_1,
       t2.datum as date_2
from   t2 left outer join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
group  by t2.id, t2.datum
;

        ID DATE_1     DATE_2    
---------- ---------- ----------
         3 09-09-2021 12-09-2021
```

I only included `id` in the output once - since you join by `id`, it makes no sense to show it twice.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy. It is working :) Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function (at least, as far as I can tell), so one option is to rank differences between dates and fetch the highest ranked row. Something like this:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  t1 (id, datum) as
  4    (select 1, date '2020-12-02' from dual union all
  5     select 2, date '2019-11-23' from dual union all
  6     select 3, date '2021-09-09' from dual union all
  7     select 3, date '2021-10-12' from dual
  8    ),
  9  t2 (id, datum) as
 10    (select 3, date '2021-09-12' from dual),
 11  --
 12  temp as
 13    -- rank difference of dates in ascending order
 14    (select b.id b_id, b.datum b_datum, a.id a_id, a.datum a_datum,
 15       rank() over (partition by a.id order by abs(b.datum - a.datum) asc) rnk
 16     from t1 a join t2 b on a.id = b.id
 17    )
 18  -- value you want is ranked the "highest"
 19  select a_id, a_datum,
 20         b_id, b_datum
 21  from temp
 22  where rnk = 1;

      A_ID A_DATUM          B_ID B_DATUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         3 09/09/2021          3 09/12/2021

SQL>
```

Comment: The OP clarified: In the case of ties, he needs just one "optimal" row selected, not all of them. Easy to modify: use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL JOIN` with `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`:

```sql
SELECT a1.*,
       a2."DATE" AS date2
FROM   a2
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT a1.*
         FROM   a1
         WHERE  a1.id = a2.id
         ORDER BY ABS(a1."DATE" - a2."DATE")
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) a1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A1 (ID, "DATE") AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-12-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2019-11-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-09-09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-10-12' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE A2 (ID, "DATE") AS
SELECT 3, DATE '2021-09-12' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DATE | DATE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 2021-09-09 00:00:00 | 2021-09-12 00:00:00 |

---

If you have multiple rows for the same `ID` in `A2` then they will each be matched with the closest row:

For example, after:

```sql
INSERT INTO a2 (id, "DATE") VALUES (3, DATE '2025-01-01');
```

Then the query above would output:

> | ID | DATE | DATE2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 2021-09-09 00:00:00 | 2021-09-12 00:00:00 |
> | 3 | 2021-10-12 00:00:00 | 2025-01-01 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=414c367d8de142f9ebc12d00544c00b8)*